# SOQL: why FIELDS() function in not supported? Test class API version 51

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test

I'm trying to use the FIELDS(ALL) function in my apex test class, in order to prevent this kind of error

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
> fields...

But I can't save class with such query, because of this error:

> The SOQL FIELDS function is not supported with an unbounded set of fields in this API.

- Api version on test class 51
- When I try to use the same query by dev console, it works fine.

Any thoughts?

[image]
[image]

Comment: check your org version, because might be that your org is created with 50.0 version, plus you'll get `duplicate field error` for `Id, FIELDS(ALL)`, it should be just `FIELDS(ALL)`

Comment: haha, yes, thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like an unbounded query is not currently supported in Apex.
This query in your test class is considered an unbound query, hence the error.

Not sure why it doesn't fail in the dev console query editor. Maybe it uses the REST API behind the scenes (?)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fields.htm

> The API distinguishes bounded queries, which have well-defined sets of fields, from unbounded queries, which have sets of fields that the API can’t determine in advance. For example, because the number of custom fields for an object isn’t predetermined, FIELDS(CUSTOM) and FIELDS(ALL) are considered unbounded. This table shows the support for FIELDS() in bounded and unbounded queries:

[image: Screeeshot of the table defining bounded vs unbounded]

Comment: Got it, thanks!